# Postgres Windows Function query too slow

Tags: postgresql, subquery, where-clause

Im trying to see how teams do vs other teams that have a record greater than .500 win/loss.
My table has cumulative records, up to the date (grouped by year and team), and the name of each opponent
on that date.

It also has non-cumulative result for that row: won or lost

```
id  team  opp   year_id   game_dt   won    lost    games_played   games_won
---------------------------------------------------------
a   ANA   TEX   1980     19800527   1        0         41             17
b   ANA   TEX   1980     19800528   1        0         42             18
c   TEX   OAK   1080     19800525   1        0         40             21
d   TEX   ANA   1980     19800527   0        1         42             22
```

The goal is to get the opponents most current record (games_won/games_played), but not including the date of the game for current row. 
I believe the logic of my query works, but it takes so long, I know this isn't going to be efficient enough for daily updates.

```
select team,opp,year_id,game_dt  from team_win_loss t1 where EXISTS (
select * from(select team,year_id,game_dt,games_won,games_played ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By year_id,team order by game_dt desc) row_number 
from team_win_loss t2 where game_dt<t1.game_dt and team=t1.opp and t1.year_id=year_id  
and cast(games_won as float)/cast(games_played as float)>=.500 ) as rows
where row_number=1 )
order by team,year_id,game_dt
```

My query is also only able to get flag if the opp is above .500, I would ideally like to have new columns outputted to show records vs above .500 and below .500 opps:

```
id  team  opp   year   game_dt   games_played   games_won  game_played_vs_winners   games_won_vs_winners   games_played_vs_losers   games_won_vs_losers
```

The only thing I could think of was to put a subquery with windows function getting the previous date.
I had to abort it it was taking so long on my data.

I don't think the 'WHERE EXISTS' is going to work either, as Ill probably need individual subqueries for each column (if opps most recent record to date is >=.500 or <.500).

Comment: The `order by game_dt desc` is useless in the sub-query - but you do need an `order by` for the `row_number()` function

Comment: And then, if you wonder about performance, please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.

Comment: Fixed the order_by